# Is Google Docs spell checking currently broken?

Tags: google-docs

I've used Menu `File-Language` to check several docs.  Then `Tools - Spelling - Spell Check`.  All I get as results is **No Spelling Suggestions**.

French language does not show any corrections, on a French text.  Switch the language to English, no corrections.  Open an English-content doc, set to English language, no suggestions.  Switch it to French language, no corrections.  Etc...

One document I opened was warning about `imagine` in English.  Why?  Then, once I told it to ignore that word it shut up despite intentional errors on my part, such as `manified` vs `magnified`.

Hey, it's free, so one can only complain so much.  But should I just totally ignore this functionality as broken, at least as of March 2018?

Comment: What web browser are you using? Are you any web browser extension?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, I run to [Google product forum with similar question](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/vyPg5DC-AQY/ShsmTf6DCQAJ).

My problem was having Grammerly installed in Chrome, which can interfere with the spell checker. If you don't have Grammerly, other extensions may interfere too.

**Try to disable or uninstall the extenstion and refresh the document. For me disabling of Grammerly has done the job.**

If neither is working, your issue is elsewhere, but I would recommend trying different web browser.